# How do duplicate brain regions (ex: left/right amygdaloid body) operate together?

Tags: brain, human-anatomy, endocrinology, neuroanatomy

I frequently hear talk about parts of the brain like "Amygdala" or "Hypothalamus", so I looked them up in an app called "essential anatomy". What I see is that there's mirror symmetry, and most of these glands/nuclei are actually mirrored in two halves of the brain.

**I'm trying to understand how two halves of nuclei like amygdala work together.** For example, it is frequently said that Amygdala processes fear response. If it was a single nucleus, it is conceptually easy to comprehend, but what about a "multi core" nuclei with two halves? Which half would process the fear response?

Additional questions to help clarify this question:

- Are duplicate nuclei connected through some nerves, making up a single organ?
- Is there a dominant/non-dominant relationship between halves (like dominant hand)?
- Or do nuclei fulfill identical role within different brain halves (right half gets scared, then left half gets scared)?

Here's an image that prompted my curiocity - it is a 3D model of nuclei that sit on top of brain stem and under white matter.

[image: Brain glands mirror image]

Comment: Regarding to amygdala, I have read somewhere that they have slightly different functions like processing negative and/or positive emotions. So maybe they are not have to be in communication? I am not sure tho. I hope somebody explain and we can learn it.

Comment: The two symmetrical counterparts of a brain compartment can interact with each other through connections in the corpus callosum. The purpose behind two regions of the same kind differs. For example, often it is to handle inputs from the two sides of the body respectively. Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lateralization_of_brain_function to get started.